# PHP ambiguous statement when setting dynamic property value of class

Tags: php, oop, properties

I have a class called `PreferenceCollection`, which I load for a user into `$_SESSION['Preferences']` once they log in to my web application.  This simple class uses magic methods for getting and setting values.  Here are the relevant parts:

```
class PreferenceCollection {
    private $prefs;

    function __construct() {
        $this->prefs=Array();
    }

    function __get($var) {
        return $this->prefs[$var];
    }

    function __set($var, $value) {
        $this->prefs[$var]=$value;
        $this->save();
    }
}
```

Later on in my code, I have found it necessary to set the value of a dynamically chosen property.  For this example, `$key='pref_some_preference'` and `value='something'`.

```
$_SESSION['Preferences']->substr($key, 5)=$value;
```

What I expect is the equivalent of `$_SESSION['Preferences']->some_preference=$value`.  That is, the `__set` magic method will be called with the first parameter of `some_preference`, and the second parameter, `$value`.

Instead, this line gives me a fatal error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Can't use method return value in write context

I assume that PHP is interpreting that I want to set the return value of the `substr()` call to something, rather than setting the property.

**Is my interpretation of what is happening correct?  How would I get around this problem?**

For now I am working around the issue with a public `set` method, but am curious how I could set that property directly.

Comment: It isn't clear what the line you give is supposed to do. Can you give a more detailed example so we can suggest a solution?

Comment: @Jon, I have added some clarification.  Please  let me know if there are additional questions, or my question is still unclear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want

```
$_SESSION['Preferences']->{substr($key, 5)} = $value;
```

The braces `{}` are required to guide the PHP parser into the correct direction ;-) Given that `$key` is `12345test` this would call `__set('test', $value)`.